# How can I overwrite uploaded file via Filefield?

Tags: nodes, entities, files

By default in Drupal 7, if I upload image.jpg via a file field in my node, save the node and then edit that same node and re-upload image.jpg, it will name it image_0.jpg.

I want to replace the image uploaded so I will only ever have image.jpg.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a technical exercise...programatically speaking, you would need to replace the element's `#value_callback`, currently [`file_managed_file_value()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_managed_file_value/7), with a custom one.

Your custom callback would invoke another custom function, a rewritten version of [`file_managed_file_save_upload()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_managed_file_save_upload/7), which would then invoke [`file_save_upload()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7) with [`FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/constant/FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE/7) as the 4th parameter, as opposed to the current value of [`FILE_EXISTS_RENAME`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/constant/FILE_EXISTS_RENAME/7).

Real-world, you don't want to do this. As soon as someone uploads an image to a different node, it will obviously overwrite the existing one called image.jpg, and that new image will be used in place of the existing one for all other nodes.

That's why the renaming functionality exists in the first place; to avoid global collisions.

Comment: I just want to add that in IMCE module, there's a setting: "Default behaviour for existing files during file uploads" which has an option: "Replace the existing file with the new one". This would be a good starting point to learn all the nuances of doing this.

Comment: Perfect! I was able to do exactly what Clive recommended and it worked. Thank you